# jquery prevent page scroll top - e.preventDefault(); and return false; not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

### I'm trying to prevent page scrolling to top. Additionally I wish to do it with e.preventDefault(); or return false; (thus other body tag solutions no good) however it appears to be ignoring these..

(.Slideshow fadeIn and fadeOut working fine.)

### however the page scrolls to the top after the (i think) after: onAfter function how to prevent this?

commented return false and e.preventDefault where it doesnt appear to work..

Thankyou in advance.

```
       if ($('.slideshow').length) {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        speed: 'fast',
        timeout: 0,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        nowrap: 1,
        before: onBefore,
        after: onAfter,
        pager: '#slide-pager ul',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (idx, slide) {
            // return selector string for existing anchor 

            return '#slide-pager ul li:eq(' + idx + ') a';
        },
        onPrevNextEvent: function (dir, id, el) {
            if (dir === true) {
                //alert('slide right');
                if (id >= 3) {
                    //alert(i);
                    $('#slide-pager_next').click();
                }
            }
            else {
                //alert('slide left');
                if (id >= 1) {
                    //alert(i);
                    $('#slide-pager_prev').click();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
};

function onBefore() {
    //e.preventDefault(); // same thing as above
    $(".chapter-content .slideshow").fadeOut("fast");
    // return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
}
function onAfter() {
    // return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
    //e.preventDefault(); // same thing as above
    $(".chapter-content .slideshow").fadeIn("100");
    // return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
}
```

Comment: are u trying scrolling while animation is on?

Answer (score 0):

i coundnt see ur demo, i may misunderstood but try this:

```
function onBefore() {
  if ( !$('.slideshow').is(':animated') ) {
    $(".chapter-content .slideshow").fadeOut("fast");
  }
}
function onAfter() {
  if ( !$('.slideshow').is(':animated') ) {
    $(".chapter-content .slideshow").fadeIn("100");
  }
}
```

Comment: or put these contidions to your click event

Comment: barlas. that doesn't appear to work. pagescroll to top remains when using the pager in the slideshow... Sorry for poor explanation of question :)

Comment: so you want to disappear .chapter-content .slideshow while ur cycle/animation is on?

Comment: barlas..i want to prevent page scrolling to the top (which is not part of the slider behaviour) when using the slider pager. that is whenever i select a slide no. the page will scroll to the top directly afterwards instead of just staying on the pagescroll where it is.